# Am I using structs in the wrong way?

Tags: c, struct

I have come across this wierd and mysterous (at least to me) error that I am finding a very hard time finding. It gives me an error at the line where I call my function `input(student_list1[MAX], &total_entries);` where the compiler says:

> incompatible type for agument 1 in 'input'

What am I doing wrong here? I sense it something very simple and stupid but I have gone through the code several times now without any avail.

```
#define MAX 10
#define NAME_LEN 15

struct person {
char name[NAME_LEN+1];
int age;
};

void input(struct person student_list1[MAX], int *total_entries);

int main(void)
{
    struct person student_list1[MAX];
    int total_entries=0, i;

    input(student_list1[MAX], &total_entries);

    for(i=0; i<total_entries; i++)
    {
        printf("Student 1:\tNamn: %s.\tAge: %s.\n", student_list1[i].name, student_list1[i].age);
    }

    return 0;
} //main end

void input(struct person student_list1[MAX], int *total_entries)
{
    int done=0;
    while(done!=1)
    {
        int i=0;
        printf("Name of student: ");
        fgets(student_list1[i].name, strlen(student_list1[i].name), stdin);
        student_list1[i].name[strlen(student_list1[i].name)-1]=0;

        if(student_list1[i].name==0) {
            done=1;
        }

        else {
            printf("Age of student: ");
            scanf("%d", student_list1[i].age);
            *total_entries++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using arrays incorrectly. Check the syntax for passing arrays to functions.

Comment: A `typedef struct person { ... } person_t;` would improve readability :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input(student_list1[MAX], &total_entries);` shoud be `input(student_list1, &total_entries);`.

In C,

```
void input(struct person student_list1[MAX], int *total_entries);
```

equals

```
void input(struct person *student_list1, int *total_entries);
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct person student_list1[MAX]` in the function argument is actually a pointer to `struct person student_list1`.

`student_list1[MAX]` you passed is a (out of bound) member of the array `struct person student_list1[MAX]`. Valid array index shoudl be between `0` to `MAX - 1`.

Change it to:

```
input(student_list1, &total_entries);
```

Note that here the array name `student_list1` is automatically converted to a pointer to `student_list1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with the code; this is my attempt at making it somewhat more robust:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define NAME_LEN 15

// use a typedef to simplify code
typedef struct person {
  char name[NAME_LEN];
  int age;
} person_t;

// size qualifier on student_list is redundent and person_t* does the same
void input(person_t *student_list, int *total_entries);

int main(void)
{
    person_t student_list[MAX];
    int total_entries, i;

    // pass array and not the non-existent 'student_list[MAX]' element
    input(student_list, &total_entries);

    for(i=0; i<total_entries; i++)
    {
        // age is an int, not a string so use %d
        printf("Student 1:\tName: %s.\tAge: %d.\n", student_list[i].name, student_list[i].age);
    }

    return 0;
} //main end

void input(person_t *student_list, int *total_entries)
{
    int done = 0, i = 0;

    *total_entries = 0;

    while (i < MAX) {
        printf("Name of student: ");

        // use NAME_LEN instead of strlen(list[i].name) because latter is
        // probably not initialized at this stage
        if (fgets(student_list[i].name, NAME_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        // detect zero-length string
        if (student_list[i].name[0] == '\n') {
            return;
        }

        printf("Age of student: ");
        scanf("%d", &student_list[i].age);
        // read the newline
        fgetc(stdin);

        *total_entries = ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jack. Im new to programming and I indeed see how your code is more robust. I´m new to programming and sometimes have trouble thinking in robust code. One question however, in your use of `fgets()` you use `NAME_LEN` definition, is that parameter of the function the max number of characters it can read, right? Also, doesnt `fgets()` read one character less than the ones it reads into the string variable? Doesnt the `student_list[i].name` miss an '\0' character?

Comment: @ArmanIqbal It will always null-terminate your string, so you may want to increase `NAME_LEN` constant to 16 :)